# .NET Standard: dependency not copied to output directory

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I'm converting a .NET Framework library to .NET Standard 2.0, because I need to use it from both an old .NET Framework project and a modern .NET 5 project

In the original library, I use the `ProtectedData` class, which is part of the .NET Framework (from the `System.Security.Cryptography` assembly).

This is not part of the base .NET Standard library, so to make it work I've added the appropriate NugetPackage, `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData`.

With this, the project compiles correctly, however when I try to run it I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData, Version=6.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

So I looked in the compilation output directory, and I see that there is no trace of a `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.DLL` file, its like the compilation system is not copying the dependency to the output directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have the referenced .dll `Copy Local` property set to `True` in the `.csproj`?

Comment: Usually, this is due to VS. If it compiles good and does not run, then you need to clean and rebuild you solution. If this does not work, start a new VS and your project.

Comment: @Saggio: it's not a local DLL, it's a NuGet package

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: tried, didn't work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found this answer on another forum, and it seems to work.

I added:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

to the .csproj file and now dependencies are being copied correctly.

Still would like an explanation as to WHY this is needed, since I never had to do this before for other projects...

Comment: Note for future readers, the `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` should be added into the csproj of the .NET standard project.

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. Because it is a .NET Standard library, it cannot run on its own, so there is no point in outputting the dependent DLLs into the libraries output directory. If you were to reference this library in an executable project, then you will see all of the dependencies get outputted (in the exe project's output folder).

Comment: I'm not sure your explanation is correct @Mayoor. I'm in the same situation, except I am dealing with an executable project, and unless I add `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies`, the transitive dependency doesn't get copied to the project's output directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are forced to use packages.config, the accepted answer won't work.

You can turn on Detailed build output to see where the compiler fails to copy the dll from the packages folder to the output folder.

To fix this, you need to add a Reference with a HintPath to the .csproj file in order for the build to resolve the reference from the packages folder.

Include should be set to the path the compiler is complaining about.
HintPath should be set to the correct path found by browsing the packages folder:

```
<Reference Include="'System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'">
  <HintPath>..\packages\PathToDll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```